# Axis2 error when generating wsdl

Tags: wsdl, jax-ws, apache-axis

I'm trying to develop a new webservice using JAX-WS and JAXB annotations.
When I deploy the .jar in axis2 and open the browser to retrieve the generated .wsdl I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Error occurred generating WSDL file for Web service implementation class {foo.bar.myServiceImpl}
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/ws/api/server/Container
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.builder.JAXWSRIWSDLGenerator.generateWsdl(JAXWSRIWSDLGenerator.java:179)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.builder.JAXWSRIWSDLGenerator.initialize(JAXWSRIWSDLGenerator.java:390)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.builder.JAXWSRIWSDLGenerator.getWSDL(JAXWSRIWSDLGenerator.java:383)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printWSDL(AxisService.java:1394)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPWorker.service(HTTPWorker.java:154)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.AxisHttpService.doService(AxisHttpService.java:281)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.AxisHttpService.handleRequest(AxisHttpService.java:187)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.HttpServiceProcessor.run(HttpServiceProcessor.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.Container
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 15 more
```

Digging in the source, i notice that the com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.Container is part of the  jaxws-rt implementation, which is not part of the Axis2 distribution (could not find it in the /lib/ folder). Why is this? Am I missing a point here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, got it. 
I'll post the answer to avoid anybody else banging his (or her) head to the wall.

I had an old JAVA_HOME environment variable set on my system. This pointed to the installer JRE, but it needs to point to the installed JDK. That's all.

Comment: Could you mark this as the accepted answer, so that it doesn't continue to show up as an unanswered question?

Comment: I would love to, but I need to wait another 21 hours according stackoverflow.

Comment: @Bjarne77 i have thesame error but i dont know how this can solve my issue , since in my java home i have java 13 jdk.

Comment: not sure @valik I think the main solution is to double check if maven points to an SDK implementation when running/building this. It's a bit too long ago to say anything valuable on this. sorry

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I need to add dependecies to jaxws-maven-plugin. Without these dependecies it throws me the same error

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl/</wsdlDirectory>
                <keep>true</keep>
                <sourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/wsimport</sourceDestDir>
                <sei></sei>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.4</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId> 
                    <version>2.1.4</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-from-wsdl</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```